# Github Actions, how to share a calculated value between job steps?

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a DRY way to calculate and share a value in multiple job steps with Github Actions?

In the below workflow yml file, **echo ${GITHUB_REF} | cut -d'/' -f3`-${GITHUB_SHA}** is repeated in multiple steps.

```
name: Test, Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_push:
    name: Build and Push
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Docker Build
        uses: "actions/docker/cli@master"
        with:
          args: build . --file Dockerfile -t cflynnus/blog:`echo ${GITHUB_REF} | cut -d'/' -f3`-${GITHUB_SHA}
      - name: Docker Tag Latest
        uses: "actions/docker/cli@master"
        with:
          args: tag cflynnus/blog:`echo ${GITHUB_REF} | cut -d'/' -f3`-${GITHUB_SHA} cflynnus/blog:latest
```

Comment: Relevant: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable and: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/

Comment: Using outputs with matrix jobs https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25634

Answer (score 131, accepted):

[`set-output`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) can be used to define outputs for steps. The outputs can then be used in later steps and evaluated in `with` and `env` input sections. Also, the step returning outputs should have an `id`, which is referred to by the step consuming the outputs.

The following is what that would look like for your example.

```
name: Test, Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_push:
    name: Build and Push
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set tag var
        id: vars
        run: echo "docker_tag=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF} | cut -d'/' -f3)-${GITHUB_SHA}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Docker Build
        uses: "actions/docker/cli@master"
        with:
          args: build . --file Dockerfile -t cflynnus/blog:${{ steps.vars.outputs.docker_tag }}
      - name: Docker Tag Latest
        uses: "actions/docker/cli@master"
        with:
          args: tag cflynnus/blog:${{ steps.vars.outputs.docker_tag }} cflynnus/blog:latest
```

Here is another example showing how to dynamically set multiple variables to be used by an action.

```
      - name: Set output variables
        id: vars
        run: |
          pr_title="[Test] Add report file $(date +%d-%m-%Y)"
          pr_body="This PR was auto-generated on $(date +%d-%m-%Y) \
            by [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request)."
          echo "pr_title=$pr_title" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "pr_body=$pr_body" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          title: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.pr_title }}
          body: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.pr_body }}
```

Alternatively you can create environment variables.

```
      - name: Set environment variables
        run: |
          echo "PR_TITLE=[Test] Add report file $(date +%d-%m-%Y)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "PR_BODY=This PR was auto-generated on $(date +%d-%m-%Y) by [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request)." >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          title: ${{ env.PR_TITLE }}
          body: ${{ env.PR_BODY }}
```

**Update:** The docker actions in the first example are deprecated. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350578/new-location-of-docker-actions/58350591#58350591) for the latest way to work with docker in GitHub Actions.

**Note:** For sharing values between *different* jobs, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175332/using-output-from-a-previous-job-in-a-new-one-in-a-github-action).

Comment: Just to be clear, these solutions do not work between steps of _different jobs_

Comment: Are this solutions deprecated?  https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/

Comment: @Sandburg No they are not deprecated. These solutions show the current way to create step outputs and environment variables.

Comment: @grokpot outputs across different jobs also seem to be supported, but you need to forward the step output to the job output: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs

Comment: Thanks! Not using quotes was the answer for me. `echo '::set-output $(date +%s) ...'` does not work but `echo ::set-output $(date +%s)...` works for substitute values.

Comment: @NecipAllef This is because (in shells in general) single quotes prevent parameter expansion. Using double quotes (`""`) would also work.

Answer (score 38):

`set-output` has been deprecated and the better way to do this is now:

```
echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Example from [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter):

```
  - name: Set color
    id: random-color-generator
    run: echo "SELECTED_COLOR=green" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  - name: Get color
    run: echo "The selected color is ${{ steps.random-color-generator.outputs.SELECTED_COLOR }}"
```

Comment: also notice that it's "SELECTED_COLOR=green" without any *space* in the beginning, because I was struggling with an output var that has a space in the beginning >" SELECTED_COLOR=green".

Comment: how can I read GITHUB_OUTPUT value inside a actions/github-script step?

Comment: If your var is secret then you need to mask it first:
    `echo "::add-mask::$my_secret"`
    `echo "MY_SECRET_VAR=$my_secret" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`