# Reference output from previous job GH Actions

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

I am attempting to use GitHub Actions for a complete pipeline, including automatic SemVer versioning (using tags) that I would then like to consume after building my Docker image to tag it with the current version. This is the [action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-tag-bump) that I am using to bump the version, which should have a new_tag output but I cannot reference it, this is what I am trying:

```yaml
jobs:
  setup:
    ...
  version:
    needs: [setup]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: '0'
    - name: Bump version and push tag
      uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.26.0
      id: autoversion
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        WITH_V: true
  sonar:
    ...
  anchore:
    ...
  docker:
    needs: [setup, version]
    steps:
      ...
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ansfire/flaskql:${{ needs.version.autoversion.outputs.new_tag }}
```

From what I have read using the `needs` key is supposed to allow one job to access upstream jobs but I cannot get it to access this. Do I need an `outputs` key in the `version` stage? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175332/using-output-from-a-previous-job-in-a-new-one-in-a-github-action/61236803#61236803), you need to define the `outputs` in the job creating the outputs, i.e.

```yaml
jobs:
  version:
    [...]
    outputs:
      new_tag: ${{ steps.autoversion.outputs.new_tag }}

  docker:
    [...] tags: ansfire/flakql:${{ needs.version.outputs.new_tag }}
```