# Reusing GitHub Action workflow steps inside another job

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have created a [Reusable Workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows) using a `workflow_call` trigger, but I need to run additional steps based on its outcome.

Example:

```yaml
jobs:
  released:
    steps:
      - name: Build
        uses: my-org/some-repo/.github/workflows/build.yml@main

      - name: Upload source maps
        run: something
```

The reusable **Build** step builds my JS app and produces source maps. Now I need to upload these source maps to somewhere as a separate step that should only run inside this **Released** job.

Doing the above results in the following error:

> Error : .github#L1
> reusable workflows should be referenced at the top-level `jobs.*.uses' key, not within steps

It only allows running my reusable workflow inside a job, not inside a step. But by doing that I can no longer access the source maps.

**My question:** How do I reuse the steps from the **Build** workflow and access its output inside the **Released** job?

Comment: if I understand correctly, might it help to split your things into multiple jobs and have the jobs communicate via outputs? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236803/1080523

Comment: @rethab If I understand correctly, outputs only work for string values. In this case I need to access the generated source map **files**.

Comment: Could the build job upload the source maps as build artifacts (using artifact-upload) and then the release job would download them again and upload them whereever else it wants to upload them?

Comment: You could create a local action using the `composite` type on this repository in the `.github/actions/<action-folder-name>` directory, and access it in your workflow job using in a step with `uses: ./.github/actions/<action-folder-name>`. This action could have an output variable that you could access in your other steps.

Comment: I've made an example: [the workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/36-local-action.yml), the [local (composite) action](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/actions/local-action/action.yaml) with an output, the [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/4238670862?check_suite_focus=true). Let me know if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can share these output files between jobs using artifacts.

Use the `upload-artifact` to upload the build files from the **Build** workflow and `download-artifact` to download them in the **Released** workflow.

#### Build workflow

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      SOME_SECRET:
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      # Your build steps here

      - name: Create build-output artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build-output
          path: build/
```

#### Released workflow

```yaml
name: Released

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    uses: my-org/some-repo/.github/workflows/build.yml@main
    secrets:
      SOME_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SOME_SECRET }}

  released:
    needs: build

    steps:
      - name: Download build-output artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build-output
          path: build/

      # The "build" directory is now available inside this job

      - name: Upload source maps
        run: something
```

**Bonus tip:** Note that the "my-org/some-repo/.github/workflows/build.yml@main" string is case-sensitive. I wasted some time figuring out that that was the cause of the error below.

> Error : .github#L1
> error parsing called workflow "my-org/some-repo/.github/workflows/build.yml@main": workflow was not found. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#access-to-reusable-workflows for more information.