# GitActions - How do I check if the logged in user is part of a team

Tags: github, github-actions

In a GitActions YAML file how do I check to see if a User is part of a Team in Github ?

I know that the username can be got via `${{ github.actor }}`

Note: The requirement is to allow only specific authorized users to be able to run a job within a workflow. (Say we restrict a step to the DBA team members)

Note: I am aware of Environments and the "Require reviewer" option. But this does not quite fit into the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [get-user-teams-membership](https://github.com/tspascoal/get-user-teams-membership) action for that. A workflow would look something like this.

```yaml
name: Check user for team affiliation
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  check-user:
    name: Team affiliation
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check user for team affiliation
        uses: tspascoal/get-user-teams-membership@v2
        id: teamAffiliation
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          team: your-team-name
      - name: Stop workflow if user is no member
        if: ${{ steps.teamAffiliation.outputs.isTeamMember == false }}
        run: |
          echo "You have no rights to trigger this job."
          exit 1
```

You can also try this with the [github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script) action. Could be a bit more difficult but also gives you more freedom.

Comment: By adding an output to the job you could use the `if` on the job level of a future job as well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75612801/my-github-env-changed-but-i-want-it-stable/75613524#75613524