# GitHub Actions: generate metrix values in a composite action

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a JSON file that contains a list of data,
In my action I have a step called 'metrix-configuration' that iterate each value in that file so it will work with a `puppeteer` step .

It all works great.

The issue is that I want to export the `metrix-configuration` step and place it in a composition action.

I have managed to take it out as an [output var](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter), but the issue that I need the data inside the `strategy` key.

How can I export the puppeteer step to an external file so will be able to use the same list in many github actions?

My current code (Works great)

```
  matrix-configuration:
    name: Matrix config
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
     - name: Checkout to repository
       uses: actions/checkout@v3
     - name: Set matrix data
       id: set-matrix
       run: echo "matrix=$(jq -c . < ./.github/scripts/puppeteer-test-suites.json)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
     - name: Generate list using Markdown
       run: |
         echo "## Matrix data ##" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
         echo "${{ fromJson(steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix) }}" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY

  puppeteer:
    name: puppeteer test
    needs: [build-plugin, matrix-configuration]
    runs-on: latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.matrix-configuration.outputs.matrix) }}
    steps:
```

I have tried to export the step to a composite file:
`get-matrix-values/action.yml`

```
name: 'puppeteer TestSuites Matrix'
description: 'Export matrix data from a JSON file'
inputs:
  puppeteer-testsuite-file: 
    description: 'puppeteer TestSuites JSON data'
    required: true
outputs:
  matrix:
    description: "the matrix data"
    value: ${{ steps.matrix-values.outputs.matrix }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Set matrix data
      id: set-matrix
      run: echo "matrix=$(jq -c . < ${{ inputs.puppeteer-testsuite-file }} )" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Generate list using Markdown
    run: |
       echo "## Matrix data ##" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
       echo "${{ fromJson(steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix) }}" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

The question is what should I do with the `strategy` key if the step that calles the composite file comes after the `strategy` key decleration

This strategy key:

```
  matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.matrix-configuration.outputs.matrix) }}
    steps:
```

This is the puppeteer action after adding the output var step and moving the `matrix-configuration` in to a file:

```
  puppeteer:
    name: puppeteer test
    needs: [build-plugin, matrix-config]
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    strategy:
      matrix: **WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?** 
    steps:
    - name: Checkout source code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - name: Get matrix values
      uses: ./.github/workflows/get-matrix-values
      id: get-matrix-values
      with:
        puppeteer-testsuite-file: './.github/scripts/puppeteer-test-suites.json'
```

Comment: This is what I did eventually. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236803