# Github action Cannot pass step output to job output

Tags: github-actions

I am having trouble passing the step output from one job to another job. When I pass the output to another job it returns an empty string

```
jobs:
  extract-branch-name:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    name: Extract branch name
    outputs:
      branch: ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.formatted_branch }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch name
        id: extract_branch
        shell: bash
        run: |
          branch="${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}}"
          formatted_branch=$(echo "$branch" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/-/g')
          echo $formatted_branch
          echo "branch=$formatted_branch" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

  push-engine-image:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    name: Push Engine Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: extract-branch-name
    steps:
      - name: Build, tag, and push ENGINE image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-engine-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        run: |
          echo "hello"
          echo ${{ needs.extract-branch-name.outputs.branch }}
          echo "hello"
          ...
```

When I look at the github action logs the `echo needs.extract-branch-name.outputs.branch` returns empty string, to be honest I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using output from a previous job in a new one in a GitHub Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175332/using-output-from-a-previous-job-in-a-new-one-in-a-github-action)

Comment: Hi Bvnch. Your issue seems to be here: `echo "branch=$formatted_branch" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`. In that case, the output name will be `branch`, and not `formatted_branch` as you stated in the output configuration in the job: `branch: ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.formatted_branch }}`. Could you validate this?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Hi yes I believe that is the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be in the first job, specifically this line:

`echo "branch=$formatted_branch" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`

With this configuration, the output name will be `branch`, and not `formatted_branch`, as you stated in the output configuration in the job, at that line:

`branch: ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.formatted_branch }}`

There are 2 ways to resolve this:

1. Update the output definition in the step,
2. Update the output config in the job output.

The updated workflow would look like this for the first option:

```
jobs:
  extract-branch-name:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    name: Extract branch name
    outputs:
      branch: ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.formatted_branch }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch name
        id: extract_branch
        shell: bash
        run: |
          branch="${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}}"
          formatted_branch=$(echo "$branch" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/-/g')
          echo $formatted_branch
          echo "formatted_branch=$formatted_branch" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT" # updated here
```