# How to reference context values in GitHub Actions expression syntax?

Tags: github-actions

I want to set an environment variable in the `env:` section of a GitHub Action and make use of the [Contexts and expression syntax for GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions). I tried this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      MYVAR: ${{ format('{0}:{1}', ${{ env.PATH }}, ${{ env.HOME }} ) }}

    steps:
    - name: Check environment
      run: echo $MYVAR
```

This results in the error message:

```
### ERRORED 10:45:52Z

- Your workflow file was invalid: The pipeline is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 10, Col: 14): Unexpected symbol: '${{'. Located at position 19 within expression: format('{0}:{1}', ${{ env.PATH
```

This syntax:

```
    env:
      MYVAR: ${{ format('{0}:{1}', {{ env.PATH }}, {{ env.HOME }} ) }}
```

results in error:

```
### ERRORED 13:14:18Z

- Your workflow file was invalid: The pipeline is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 10, Col: 14): Unexpected symbol: '{{'. Located at position 19 within expression: format('{0}:{1}', {{ env.PATH
```

and:

```
    env:
      MYVAR: ${{ format('{0}:{1}', env.PATH, env.HOME ) }}
```

results in error:

```
### ERRORED 13:16:12Z

- Your workflow file was invalid: The pipeline is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 10, Col: 14): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 19 within expression: format('{0}:{1}', env.PATH, env.HOME )
```

I'm aware of the solutions in [How do i set an env var with a bash expression in GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968497/how-do-i-set-an-env-var-with-a-bash-expression-in-github-actions) and [Github Actions, how to share a calculated value between job steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819539/github-actions-how-to-share-a-calculated-value-between-job-steps) for setting environment variables, but I would like to understand the expression syntax.

Comment: Why have you put `${{` inside `${{`? Also note that [`format`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#format) takes 0-based indices.

Comment: Because it says under https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts :

"Contexts are a way to access information about workflow runs, runner environments, jobs, and steps. Contexts use the expression syntax.

{{ <context> }}"

Comment: None of the examples on that page, including those using contexts, have more than one `${{`. I'd guess you want `${{ format('{0}:{1}', env.PATH env.HOME) }}`.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the 0-based index, I missed that. But it doesn't help. With the syntax you proposed I get: "- Your workflow file was invalid: The pipeline is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 10, Col: 14): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 19 within expression: format('{0}:{1}', env.PATH, env.HOME )"

Comment: Have you done research around that new error message, then?

Comment: I had alread tried the syntax that you proposed. This was the third try in the original question. Note that  I fixed the indices in the format string now.

Comment: But that's *not* a similar error message. Sure the start is the same, but the *reason* is different. `Unexpected symbol: '${{'.` is not the same as `Unrecognized named-value: 'env'.` I would recommend researching those specific parts of the error, and including that in your question to make it more searchable.

Comment: For example, the specific error around named-value led me to https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-use-env-context/td-p/38951 - *"You cannot use env context in the value of a workflow environment variable."*

Answer (score 5):

At the start of a workflow, the `env` context doesn't exist yet. This is why you get an error. Moreover, the first step in every job sees an empty `env` context, so even if `env` existed, the result of printing `MYVAR` would have been just `:`.

I came to the above conclusions from running some experiments.

```yaml
env:
  MYVAR: ${{ format('{0}:{1}', env.PATH, env.HOME) }}
```

The last syntax you used is the correct form, but because the `env` context doesn't exist yet, the workflow fails to run.

To prove to yourself that the `env` context is in fact empty at the first step, try the following job:

```yaml
jobs
  env-dump-context:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo env is: ${{ toJSON(env) }}
```

With that being said, it is still possible to what you need:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: printf "MYVAR=${PATH}:${HOME}" | tee --append "$GITHUB_ENV"
      - name: Check environment
        run: echo ${{env.MYVAR}}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out, it is not possible to use the `env` context in the value of a workflow environment variable. This was discussed here:

https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-use-env-context/td-p/38951

Comment: It looks like it is being tracked internally to be implemented some day https://github.community/t/use-env-variable-for-jobs-id-runs-on-and-jobs-id-services-image/17281/3 .