# Reference the runner context in job's env clause

Tags: github-actions

Here's a GitHub Actions workflow file for a Python project named `spam`:

```yaml
name: PyInstaller

on:
  [...]

jobs:
  create_release:
    [...]

  make_artifact:
    needs: create_release

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ ubuntu-latest, windows-latest ]

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    env:
      ARTIFACT_PATH: dist/spam.zip
      ARTIFACT_NAME: spam-${{ runner.os }}.zip
    
    steps:
      [...]
```

When this runs, the workflow fails at startup with this:

```
The workflow is not valid. [...]: 
Unrecognized named-value: 'runner'. Located at position 1 within expression: runner.os
```

I'm attempting to use the `os` attribute of the [`runner` context](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#runner-context). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809764/how-to-reference-context-values-in-github-actions-expression-syntax) SO Q&A mentions that the `env` context can only be used in specific places, so I suspect something similar is happening here. However, I can't find any official documentation addressing this.

Is there any way to reference the `runner` context to set an environment variable within the `env` clause of a job, as shown above?

I'm looking for a way to set the environment variable for all steps in the job, so an `env` inside a `step` item won't do.
The workaround I've got for now is to add a step specifically to set environment variables:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Setup environment
    run: |
      echo "ARTIFACT_NAME=spam-${{ runner.os }}.zip" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

however this only works on the Linux runner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you scroll down a bit further in the GitHub Actions docs you linked, there's an example workflow printing different contexts to the log.

```yaml
- name: Dump runner context
        env:
          RUNNER_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(runner) }}
```

I set up a [test repo](https://github.com/jidicula/test-actions/blob/5f8a21dccd864b926895734ec5d7144c35c48395/.github/workflows/main.yml) with a [workflow demonstration](https://gist.github.com/jidicula/4a3bde422bce94f4fb95b19a14bdaaea):

```yaml
on: push

jobs:
  one:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os:
          - 'ubuntu-latest'
          - 'windows-latest'
          - 'macos-latest'
    steps:
      - name: Dump runner context
        env:
          RUNNER_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(runner) }}
        run: echo "$RUNNER_CONTEXT"
      - name: Get runner OS
        env:
          RUNNER_OS: ${{ runner.os }}
        run: echo "$RUNNER_OS"
      - name: Create file with runner OS in name
        env:
          OS_FILENAME: 'spam-${{ runner.os }}.zip'
        run: |
          echo "OS_FILENAME=spam-${{ runner.os }}.zip" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          touch "./${{ env.OS_FILENAME }}"
          touch blah.txt
      - name: List created file
        run: ls -l "./${{ env.OS_FILENAME }}"
```

It looks like you can also set and access `env` in steps, and those persist across workflow steps. For example, I set the environment variable `$OS_FILENAME` in step 3 using the [`echo` syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable), and reference it in step 4. This works across all the OS options offered on GitHub Actions.

Note that the GitHub Actions docs state that "Environment variables must be explicitly referenced using the env context in expression syntax or through use of the $GITHUB_ENV file directly; environment variables are not implicitly available in shell commands.". Basically, it means you can't implicitly refer to env variables like `$FOO` and instead must refer to them as `${{ env.FOO }}` in shell commands.

So for your scenario, does it satisfy your requirements if you set `$ARTIFACT_NAME` in the first step of the job? I wonder if the reason might be that the `runner` context isn't created until the first step - I'm not sure I have a way of testing this.

Comment: Good catch @RuudHelderman, I just modified my workflow to [create another dummy file](https://github.com/jidicula/test-actions/blob/11e829783855ca5a0dca3bd77dabbe7b6138feb8/.github/workflows/main.yml#L26) and as you said, the `ls -l` command indeed has an empty arg :( . I'm going to retry some stuff, as I've definitely written to an env variable in a previous step and used that var in a subsequent step in some workflows I've made.

Comment: @RuudHelderman I've updated my answer to a correct implementation that persists environment variables across steps. The docs also have a [minimal reproducible example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).