# Conditional "needs" in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow that looks like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build

    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build, test]

    steps:
      - run: echo "deploy"
```

Now, I'd like to make it so that the `deploy` step only needs the `tests` step if the branch is `main`.

Is that possible?

Essentially I'd love to do something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build

    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: contains(branch, "master") ? [build, test] : [build] #notice this line

    steps:
      - run: echo "deploy"
```

Comment: Would e.g. `${{ (contains(branch, "master") && [build, test]) || [build] }}` work? There are some options for conditional expressions at https://github.community/t/do-expressions-support-ternary-operators-to-change-their-returned-value/18114

Answer (score 17):

GitHub action isn't allowing conditional needs (unfortunately, imho).

Yet, there is a workaround:
Make your jobs run sequentially by defining the prerequisites in `needs`. All jobs required to run no matter what happened to the prerequisites need get the `if` condition set to `always()`.

If a failure of a previous job is supposed to kill you need to add a step for verifying the job result(s).

This is an general solution for adaption:

```
jobs:
  init_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "initial run"

  conditional_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: init_job
    if: ${{ your condition here }}
    steps:
      - run: echo "conditonal run"

  final_job:
    needs: conditional_job
    if: always()
    steps:
      - name: fail if conditional job failed
        if: ${{ needs.conditional_job.result == 'failure' }}
        run: exit 1
      - run: echo "final run"
```

Comment: To aggregate multiple conditional jobs in `needs`, the step condition could be
`if: ${{ contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') }}`

Comment: This solution works, but be mindful about it. `always()` jobs cannot be cancelled, so if they get stuck, that's it. Use it together with a timeout (bug discussion here: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26303).

Answer (score 3):

Not ideal but you can use this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build

    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  deploy-main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    needs: [build, test]

    steps:
      - run: echo "deploy"
        
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref != 'refs/heads/main'
    needs: build

    steps:
      - run: echo "deploy"
```

Comment: The problem is that the deploy steps are really long and complex, so that's unfortunately not useful for me at the moment.

Comment: You can consider [composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action) to avoid repeating yourself

Comment: And please also check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809764/how-to-reference-context-values-in-github-actions-expression-syntax) I'm afraid that you won't be able to use `github` or `env` context in `needs` scope. When I use that I got `Unrecognized named-value: 'env'`

Comment: Hmmm, with composite actions, would I be able to have them locally? Or do they need to be hosted in a separate repo?

Comment: You can have them in the same repo. Please check it [here](https://github.com/kmadof/github-actions-manual/blob/main/.github/workflows/so-010-composite.yaml)

Comment: But they (composite actions) seem to be still limited - please check this [topic](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/646)

Comment: If the test job gets skipped then does deploy-main still run?

Answer (score 3):

As replied above there is no way to use conditions in `needs` but you can split your workflow into two:

`deploy-master.yml`:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build

    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build, test]

    steps:
      - run: echo "deploy"
```

`deploy-pr.yml`:

```
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - master
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "build"

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build]

    steps:
      - run: echo "deploy"
```

Also because you mentioned that your `deploy` job is "really long and complex" You can define it in a separate file and refer to it as to [a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows)