# GitHub Actions: How to dynamically set environment url based on deployment step output?

Tags: github, github-actions, environment

I found out about [a really nice GitHub Actions Feature called Environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments). Using the appropriate syntax [a Environment could also be created inside a GitHub Action `workflow.yml`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment) like this:

```
environment:
  name: test_environment
  url: https://your-apps-url-here.com
```

[As the docs state](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments#creating-an-environment) thats a valid way to create GitHub Action Environments:

> Running a workflow that references an environment that does not exist
> will create an environment with the referenced name.

But inside my current GitHub Action workflow is there a way I dynamically set the `url` based on a deployment step output? I have a dynamic URL resulting from the deployment process to AWS which I can't define up-front.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The job workflow docs tell us that [there's also a way of using expressions inside the `url` field](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment):

```
environment:
  name: test_environment
  url: ${{ steps.step_name.outputs.url_output }}
```

Now imagine a `ci.yml` workflow file that uses AWS CLI to deploy a static website to S3, where we used a tool like Pulumi to dynamically create a S3 Bucket inside our AWS account. We can read the dynamically created S3 url using the following command `pulumi stack output bucketName`. The deploy step inside the `ci.yml` could then look like this:

```
  - name: Deploy Nuxt.js generated static site to S3 Bucket via AWS CLI
    id: aws-sync
    run: |
      aws s3 sync ../dist/ s3://$(pulumi stack output bucketName) --acl public-read
      echo "s3_url=http://$(pulumi stack output bucketUrl)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    working-directory: ./deployment
```

There are 2 crucial points here: First we should use `id` inside the deployment step to define a step name we could easily access via `step_name` inside our `environment:url`. Second [we need to define a step output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57989070/4964553) using `echo "s3_url=http://$(pulumi stack output bucketUrl)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`. In this example I create a variable `s3_url`. You could replace the `pulumi stack output bucketUrl` with any other command you'd like or tool you use, which responds with your dynamic environment url.

Be also sure to add a `http://` or `https://` in order to prevent an error message like this:

```
Environment URL 'microservice-ui-nuxt-js-hosting-bucket-bc75fce.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph.
```

Now the `environment` definition at the top of our `ci.yml` can access the `s3_url` output variable from our deployment step like this:

```
jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    environment:
      name: microservice-ui-nuxt-js-deployment
      url: ${{ steps.aws-sync.outputs.s3_url }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        ...
```

Using `steps.aws-sync` we reference the deployment step directly, since we defined it with the `id`. The appended `.outputs.s3_url` then directly references the variable containing our S3 url. If you defined everything correctly the GitHub Actions UI will render the environment URL directly below the finished job:

[image]

Here's also [a fully working workflow embedded inside a example project](https://github.com/jonashackt/microservice-ui-nuxt-js/blob/main/.github/workflows/static-site-pulumi-aws-s3-deploy.yml).

**Update**: The `set-output name=VARNAME::VALUE` notation [is deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/) and produces the following output (thanks Rob for pointing that out!):

```
Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
```

Comment: "a fully working workflow embedded inside a example project." the link is broken

Comment: Just fixed the link!

Comment: That's a bummer that we still can't set it during the job execution. As for myself, the job that deploys to my environments also outputs the dynamically generated URL. Hence I must create an extra job just to set the URL which is not a viable solution

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addendum, if you run the accepted answer today (3/8/2023) you will get a deprecation warning. Set-output will be removed in the future. The accepted answer can be rewritten as

```
  - name: Deploy Nuxt.js generated static site to S3 Bucket via AWS CLI
    id: aws-sync
    run: |
      aws s3 sync ../dist/ s3://$(pulumi stack output bucketName) --acl public-read
      echo "s3_url=http://$(pulumi stack output bucketUrl)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```