# Access a variable created in another job when using Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

Using Github Actions I have the following jobs (I omitted code for sake of simplicity:

version:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest  

steps:

- name: Setup
  uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.9.7
  id: gitversion
```

build:

```
needs: [version]
runs-on: ubuntu-latest  

steps:

- name: Build
  run: dotnet pack src/Proj.csproj -p:Version=???
```

How to access the gitversion value in build job step?

Comment: You can save the `gitversion` as [output](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs) in the `version` job , to use it in the `build` job. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819539/github-actions-how-to-share-a-calculated-value-between-job-steps) can give you more context.

Comment: The gitversion action produces many outputs. You need to specify which one you were interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you were interested in the `semVer` output, define job outputs for the build job

```yaml
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
outputs:
   semVer: ${{steps.gitversion.outputs.semVer}}

steps:
  - name: Setup
    uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.9.7
    id: gitversion
```

```yaml
needs: [version]
runs-on: ubuntu-latest  

steps:
  - name: Build
    run: dotnet pack src/Proj.csproj -p:Version=${{needs.version.outputs.semVer}}
```