# How do I set an env var with a bash expression in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

In GitHub Actions, I'd like to evaluate a bash expression and then assign it to an environment variable:

```yaml
    - name: Tag image
      env:
        GITHUB_SHA_SHORT: ${{ $(echo $GITHUB_SHA | cut -c 1-6) }}
      ..do other things...
```

However, this naive attempt has failed. [According to the docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#literals) this doesn't seem to be supported; a somewhat clean workaround would be fine.

Comment: Maybe `set-env` would work in a previous step. https://help.github.com/en/articles/development-tools-for-github-actions#set-an-environment-variable-set-env

Answer (score 409, accepted):

The original answer to this question used the Actions runner function `set-env`. Due to a [security vulnerability](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/) `set-env` is being deprecated and should no longer be used.

This is the new way to set environment variables.

```yaml
name: my workflow
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set env
      run: echo "GITHUB_SHA_SHORT=$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | cut -c 1-6)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: Test
      run: echo $GITHUB_SHA_SHORT
```

> Setting an environment variable
> `echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV`
>
> Creates or updates an environment variable for any actions running next in a job. The action that creates or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new value, but all subsequent actions in a job will have access. Environment variables are case-sensitive and you can include punctuation.

(From https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)

Example using the output to $GITHUB_ENV method:

```
    echo "GITHUB_SHA_SHORT=$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | cut -c 1-6)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

This is an alternative way to reference the environment variable in workflows.

```
    - name: Test
      run: echo ${{ env.GITHUB_SHA_SHORT }}
```

Comment: Removed the extra curly brackets (unnecessary as they become part of the value) and added link to doc. Thanks!

Comment: @evilSnobu Not sure if it fits your use case, but there is another similar method for passing values to later steps using `set-output` that I've detailed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819539/github-actions-how-to-share-a-calculated-value-between-job-steps/57989070#57989070

Comment: what about setting multiple keys and values? Do we just duplicate that same command or is there a way to do it with 1 command?

Comment: @SudoPlz I think the only way is to duplicate the `set-env` command, yes. You can execute multiple `set-env` commands in the same `run` step, though.

Comment: `echo ${{ env.GITHUB_SHA_SHORT }}` I think that is not an alternative syntax, but it uses the Github template engine. That means that  you can embed the env variable on places where you usually will not be able to, while `$VARNAME` is only available to shell environment

Comment: Just a quick note (since this caused me headache). If you are using a Windows/PowerShell environment, you have to use `$env:GITHUB_ENV`, i.e. something like `run: echo "GITHUB_SHA_SHORT=$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | cut -c 1-6)" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV`.

Comment: BEWARE of the fine print :) "The action that creates or updates the environment variable DOES NOT have access to the new value, but all subsequent actions in a job will have access."

Comment: But what about if I want to use this variable in multiple jobs? Is there any way to define a workflow level variable?

Comment: I, too, got bitten by the curly braces in the quoted section.

Comment: ruby script: `db_url = "postgresql://#{user}:#{RDS_PASSWORD}@#{host}:#{port}/#{db_name}"`
this means, then i could set the ENV variable out of a ruby script and then re-use it in another script later in life
`DATABASE_URL='#{db_url}' >> $GITHUB_ENV`

Comment: Github f*ctions become uglier and uglier. Pray for to not ruin it like anything else MS has ruined.

Comment: `tee -a` is slightly more useful than `>>`: it shows the newly set environment variable in the output.

Comment: @honey_ramgarhia, I was wondering the same thing and found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485275/13040522
Basically you need to create a workflow env variable, set it in the echo statement and then output it from the job since they run on different virtual machines

Comment: This doesn't answers the question. This works only in `run` part, but how to set the same in `env` for the step?

This doesn't work:
```
env:
        GITHUB_SHA_SHORT:  $GITHUB_SHA_SHORT
        GITHUB_SHA_SHORT:  ${{ env.GITHUB_SHA_SHORT }}
```

Comment: I just printed most of the variables, I couldn't post here because of the length limitation. You can check it out here (Print vars section): https://github.com/wxw-matt/test_release/actions/runs/4587386341/jobs/8100853262

Comment: Quick note: For this to work for me, I had to make some changes. What worked for me is adding quotes around $GITHUB_ENV when assigning the variable. That is, `... >> "$GITHUB_ENV"`. And I could only access the variable in a new step, not within the same step in which I assigned the variable. This is the GitHub docs page that I followed: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-writing-an-environment-variable-to-github_env

Answer (score 13):

```
  - name: Set and Retrieve Github ENV variables
    shell: bash
    run: |

      # define variables      
      tests=16
      failures=2

      # set them as GitHub ENV variables
      echo "Tests=$tests" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo "Failures=$failures" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      # retrieve these GitHub ENV variables
      echo "${{ env.Failures }} out of ${{ env.Tests }} tests failed on CI"
```

### Output

```
  2 out of 16 test failed on CI
```

Comment: Nice. Is this documented somewhere, could you add a reference? Does it persist for subsequent steps?

Comment: @evilSnobu No documentation, this what I'm using

Comment: This isn't working for me. The final output is ` out of  tests failed on CI` without the `env.Failures` and `env.Tests` values.

Comment: What worked for me is adding quotes around $GITHUB_ENV when assigning the variable. That is, `... >> "$GITHUB_ENV"`. And I could only access the variable in a new step, not within the same step in which I assigned the variable. This is the GitHub docs page that I followed: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-writing-an-environment-variable-to-github_env

Comment: You cannot access environment variables created this way in the same step, they become available in the next step and beyond.

Answer (score -6):

The documentation https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#about-environment-variables describes 2 ways of defining environment-variables.

> To set custom environment variables, you need to specify the variables
> in the workflow file. You can define environment variables for a step,
> job, or entire workflow using the jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env,
> jobs.<job_id>.env, and env keywords.

```
steps:
  - name: Hello world
    run: echo Hello world $FIRST_NAME $middle_name $Last_Name!
    env:
      FIRST_NAME: Mona
      middle_name: The
      Last_Name: Octocat
```

> You can also use the GITHUB_ENV environment file to set an environment
> variable that the following steps in a workflow can use. The
> environment file can be used directly by an action or as a shell
> command in a workflow file using the run keyword.

Comment: Ok, but can you evaluate a bash expression under `env: FIRST_NAME:`?

Comment: For me, it works perfectly, but I use env. var. from a python script. Thanks!