# Github Action - use Variable in the script

Tags: variables, yaml, github-actions

With [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) how to do a backup of a file?

I need to create a new folder named with the date/time of today.

```
name: Backup Database

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Backup
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
          port: 22
          script: |
            DATE=${{ NEW DATE }} # Need to create a variable with date/time
            mkdir backup_${{ DATE }} # Create a new folder with the date/time
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i set an env var with a bash expression in GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968497/how-do-i-set-an-env-var-with-a-bash-expression-in-github-actions)

Comment: yep it is! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This user found a hack to create vars that are generated with bash commands output.

In his words:

> I found a way to hack this limitation.  Write your VAR on disk (the CI
> system disk),  then cat $my_var to use your VAR in every step you need

Reference: "[How to define env variable?](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/68#issuecomment-524937002)"

Comment: Another hack in the same thread:

https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/68#issuecomment-552074596