# How do I set an enviroment variable in GitHub action on a Windows Server?

Tags: github-actions

First of all let me explain what I'm trying to do. I do write a c# .net application which I want to build if a tag was pushed to the master branch. This build should create a release named like `Release {Tag}`. The release should get all the artifacts which got build by the Windows Server. Right now I fail to get the tag only without the stuff in front of it.

I did find a question on how to set an environment variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968497/how-do-i-set-an-env-var-with-a-bash-expression-in-github-actions) but this seems to work on linux only like this. I did try to find the information in the official [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) but I don't get it into a working state. Currently I'm using the following code trying to get the tag from the commit.

```
name: Live build

on: [push]
  #push:
  #  tags:
  #   - '*'

jobs:
   build:
     name: Create build artifact
     runs-on: windows-latest
     steps:
       - name: Clone repository
         uses: actions/checkout@v2
         with: 
           ref: develop
       - name: Get current tag
         run: echo '::set-env name=tag::${(("${env:GITHUB_REF}" -split "/")[-1] -replace " ","")}'
       - name: Show current tag
         run: echo "${env.tag}"
```

Unfortunately this is the result, which does not look correct to me

**[image: 1]**

I did try to replace this part `echo '::set-env name=tag::${(("${env:GITHUB_REF}" -split "/")[-1] -replace " ","")}'` the call with the following test

- `echo '::set-env name=tag::(("${env:GITHUB_REF}" -split "/")[-1] -replace " ","")'`
- `echo '::set-env name=tag::$(("${env:GITHUB_REF}" -split "/")[-1] -replace " ","")'`
- `echo ::set-env name=tag::$(("${env:GITHUB_REF}" -split "/")[-1] -replace " ","")`
- `echo ::set-env name=tag::(("${env:GITHUB_REF}" -split "/")[-1] -replace " ","")`

Nothing did work just yet ... The default shell is set to powershell in this setup.

edit: Adding documentation from GitHub

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With the latest changes to Github, the `set-env` command is deprecated. The new [recommended](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) way is to append text in UTF-8 encoding to a Github environmental file.

This is how I do it to get the current branch's name in windows powershell:

```
- run: |
   chcp 65001 #set code page to utf-8
   echo ("BRANCH_NAME=" + $env:GITHUB_REF.replace('refs/heads/', '')) >> $env:GITHUB_ENV

- run: echo "${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}"
- run: echo $env:BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: Key here is to use `$env:GITHUB_ENV` on Windows. This is not mentioned in the Github Actions docs, sadly.

Comment: There is a passing reference to using `$env` when running on Windows at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#detecting-the-operating-system

Comment: Mine was erroring because I was doing `$env:$GITHUB_ENV` instead of `$env:GITHUB_ENV`.

Answer (score 2):

#### The method described in this answer is now deprecated. Please use this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65110357/2089675).

---
Use this:

```
run: echo "::set-env name=tag::$(($env:GITHUB_REF -split '/')[-1] -replace ' ','')"
```

To get the variable, you just access it as if it were an environment variable:

```
run: echo "${env:tag}"
```

Comment: `set-env` was removed on 11/19/2020 due to a security issue: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-11-09-github-actions-removing-set-env-and-add-path-commands-on-november-16/
See Sal's answer for the new recommended way.

Comment: Changed the Answer :) Thank you for mentioning. Just took me a while to register it :D

Answer (score 0):

As reported here https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1636 in the Windows runner, the shell is Powershell thus setting the environment variables is different:

Instead of what you would do in Linux or macOS

```yaml
run: echo "var=value" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

You should do

```yaml
run: echo "var=value" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append
```

Of course, you can have conditional steps based on the current runner, e.g.,

```yaml
- name: Set environment variable
  run: echo "var=value" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
  if: runner.os != 'Windows'
- name: Set environment variable on Windows
  run: echo "var=value" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append
  if: runner.os == 'Windows'
```

And you can test it like that

```yaml
- name: Show environment variable
  run: echo ${{ env.var }}
```