# How do I inject environment variables and secrets into Github action pipeline using config.json

Tags: node.js, github-actions, building-github-actions

How do I inject secrets and environment variables residing in my config.json to GitHub action in nodejs?

For instance

```
{
   apiKey: "blablabla",
   apiId: "anotherblabla"
}
```

Comment: You can't read a JSON natively in Github Actions (yet?). Here, you would have to use a customized **script** or **shell commands** to extract the variables from the JSON, and then inject them as an env variable using something like this: `echo "apiKey=$API_KEY_EXTRACTED_VALUE" >> $GITHUB_ENV` (or inject them as secrets using for example the Github CLI [gh secret set](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_secret_set)).

Comment: Actually, I read from [this thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919141/read-json-file-in-github-actions) that there is a [fromJson](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) function that can be used to provide a JSON object as an evaluated expression or to convert environment variables from a string. That may be the solution in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use github CLI and you get many options on how to inject secrets:

##### Paste secret value for the current repository in an interactive prompt

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET
```

##### Read secret value from an environment variable

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET --body "$ENV_VALUE"
```

##### Read secret value from a file

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET < myfile.txt
```

##### Set secret for a deployment environment in the current repository

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET --env myenvironment
```

##### Set organization-level secret visible to both public and private repositories

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET --org myOrg --visibility all
```

##### Set organization-level secret visible to specific repositories

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET --org myOrg --repos repo1,repo2,repo3
```

##### Set user-level secret for Codespaces

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET --user
```

##### Set repository-level secret for Dependabot

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET --app dependabot
```

##### Set multiple secrets imported from the ".env" file

```
$ gh secret set -f .env
```