# GitHub Action - Define Workflow Level Environment Variable Between Jobs

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to define and set environment variable between jobs inside my Github Actions Workflow.
The workflow below is what I've tried but unfortunately the environment variable **GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT** and **E2E_GIT_PR_SHA** not working.

Is it possible?

```
name: Git Pull Request Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  GIT_PR_SHA: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.sha}}
  GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT: "${{ env.GIT_PR_SHA:0:10 }}"
  ENV_NAME: test
  E2E_GIT_PR_SHA: "${{ env.ENV_NAME }}-${{ env.GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT }}"

jobs:
  first-job:
    name: Build Docker Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: First Echo Step
      run: |
            echo "GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT = ${GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT}"
            echo "E2E_GIT_PR_SHA = ${E2E_GIT_PR_SHA}"

  second-job:
    name: Build Docker Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Second Echo Step
      run: |
            echo "GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT = ${GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT}"
            echo "E2E_GIT_PR_SHA = ${E2E_GIT_PR_SHA}"
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You reference *a workflow's* environment variables with `${{ env.VARIABLE_NAME }}` not `${VARIABLE_NAME}`.  The latter is bash syntax, but these are not shell environment variables, they're *workflow* environment variables.  They're part of the workflow execution, not part of the shell's context.

To reference a workflow environment variable:

```
name: Git Pull Request Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  one: 1
  two: zwei
  three: tres

jobs:
  first-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo "${{ env.one }}"
        echo "${{ env.two }}"
        echo "${{ env.three }}"
```

(I like to use `lower-case` for my workflow environment variables, and `UPPER_CASE` for my shell environment variables, so that it's more obvious to me which is which.)

Similarly, this won't work:

```
env:
  GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT: "${{ env.GIT_PR_SHA:0:10 }}"
```

This is mixing bash syntax `:0:10` with the workflow syntax, but the workflow variables are not run through any shell.  No virtual machine has been started when the workflow file is parsed, so there's no shell to run things though.

If you wanted to use bash expressions to manipulate the environment, you would need to create a step that runs bash to do that, and you would need to use the `::set-env` or `::set-output` syntax.

Then you can refer to a `step`'s output using the `${{ steps... }}` context.

Unfortunately, passing things between *different jobs* is trickier, since they run on different virtual machines.  You'll need to set variables on the overall workflow itself.  You'll need to first `::set-output` so that it's visible to the *job*, then you can raise the visibility from the job to the workflow.

```
name: Demonstration
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  first-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
    - id: identify
      run: |
        # use bash variable expression to get the substring
        export GIT_PR_SHA="${{ github.sha }}"
        export GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT="${GIT_PR_SHA:0:10}"

        echo "::set-output name=git_pr_sha::${GIT_PR_SHA}"
        echo "::set-output name=git_pr_sha_short::${GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT}"
    outputs:
      git_pr_sha: ${{ steps.identify.outputs.git_pr_sha }}
      git_pr_sha_short: ${{ steps.identify.outputs.git_pr_sha_short }}

  second-job:
    needs: first-job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo "${{ needs.first-job.outputs.git_pr_sha }}"
        echo "${{ needs.first-job.outputs.git_pr_sha_short }}"
```

Comment: The first part of this is not exactly correct. I have no issues just using the $WORKFLOW_VAR syntax for those top-level workflow env vars as long as it is within a bash/script execution.  However, I have to use the ${{ env.VAR }} style to provide the values for an imported step parameter or other situations where it's not within a bash script.

Comment: If I'm going to use `set-output` as a way of variable sharing, what can we do if the first job is a matrix-supported one?

Comment: `set-output` and `set-state` are going to be removed. The alternative is `echo "key=value" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` . See more at https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to add an extension to this since I've had similar difficulties finding how to compute & set environment variables for multi-step use.

Below is a basic example of how to push back to the github environment from within a step if processing is needed to compute an environment variable for later use. You can also update existing variables this same way, not just create new.

```
name: minimal variable example

on:
  push:

env:
  MAJOR:                        "1"
  MINOR:                        "0"
  PATCH:                        "1"

jobs:
  vars-example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: only available local variable
        run: LOCAL_VERSION=${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}

      - name: available across multiple steps
        run: echo "GLOBAL_VERSION=${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Vars
        run: |
          echo LOCAL_VERSION = $LOCAL_VERSION
          echo GLOBAL_VERSION = $GLOBAL_VERSION
```

which results in Vars output of

```
  echo LOCAL_VERSION = $LOCAL_VERSION
  echo GLOBAL_VERSION = $GLOBAL_VERSION
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    MAJOR: 1
    MINOR: 0
    PATCH: 1
    GLOBAL_VERSION: 1.0.1
LOCAL_VERSION =
GLOBAL_VERSION = 1.0.1
```

Comment: And because I just came across it again. Here's the link to github's explanation.  https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

Answer (score 6):

The following is the newer way of sharing the variables across jobs after the [deprication](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)

- Have also covered the scenario when the `value` itself is a variable and needs to be computed at runtime.
- The following would be invoked when a push is made `master` branch

```yaml
name: Sharing envs across jobs

on:
  push:
    branches: ['master']

env:
  one: onevalue
  two: twovalue
  three: threevalue

jobs:
  job0:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "${{ env.one }}"
          echo "${{ env.two }}"
          echo "${{ env.three }}"

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
      output2: ${{ steps.step2.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: echo "test=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")-asdfads223" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - id: step2
        run: echo "test=world" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}} ${{needs.job1.outputs.output2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `env` in an expression under the `env` element. I don't see another way than using duplicate values instead of an expression.

> The `env` context syntax allows you to use the value of an environment variable in your workflow file. You can use the `env` context in the value of any key in a **step** except for the `id` and `uses` keys. For more information on the step syntax, see ["Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps).

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#env-context

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, let me rephrase my question.
How can I set both environment variable GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT (a 10 first digits of GIT SHA) and E2E_GIT_PR_SHA (Concatenate of previous envs ENV_NAME and GIT_PR_SHA_SHORT) and make them to be available to every step and job in a github action workflow run.

I prefer not to duplicate the same (::set-env) code several time for each step and job within the workflow.