# Use an array in workflow level env variable?

Tags: github-actions

You can set env vars available across the entire workflow e.g. [like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467662/github-action-define-workflow-level-environment-variable-between-jobs).

(From solution on linked post)

```
name: Git Pull Request Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  one: 1
  two: zwei
  three: tres

jobs:
  first-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo "${{ env.one }}"
        echo "${{ env.two }}"
        echo "${{ env.three }}"
```

I have a workflow that uses a matrix strategy and I have to update it in each job if I ever change it. I tried to make it a global variable like above:

```
name: Model Multipliers
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    
env:
  FRUIT: ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Orange"]

jobs:
  ssql-get:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        FRUIT: ${{ env.FRUIT }}
    name: Get data
    steps:
      - name: Checkout cum-rev repo
```

But this gives error:

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 12, Col:
> 9): A sequence was not expected .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 19,
> Col: 15): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1
> within expression: env.FRUIT

Is what I'm trying to do possible by any other means?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `bash`, you can create a regular array (like in bash) to use in your steps or inside github expressions -

Example:

```yaml
env:
  MAIN_BRANCHES: ("develop" "main")
```

Now you can use the array in any step. In the run property, as an environment variable with `"${MAIN_BRANCHES}"`, or inside `if` conditions with Github expression syntax.

```yaml
...
    - name: Tag build
      if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && contains(env.MAIN_BRANCHES, steps.calculate_changed_services.outputs.diff_dest) }}
      run: echo "my main branches ${MAIN_BRANCHES}"
...
```

You can find the full Workflow File here - [gitversion.yml](https://github.com/mrsauravsahu/blog-semver-monorepo/blob/develop/.github/workflows/gitversion.yml)

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the double quotes in the values it should work

Comment: I tried this and it failed. It failed when referencing the values, e.g. in env I have `env:
  FRUIT: [Apple, Pear, Banana, Orange]` then further down when I reference I have `matrix:
        FRUIT: ${{ env.FRUITS }}` then when I run the workflow I get error "The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 9, Col: 10): A sequence was not expected .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 16, Col: 15): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.FRUITS"

Comment: `[]` is a JSON array, not bash so you'll need `fromJson( ${{ env.FRUITS }} )`