# Variables set via output are not passed along in jobs in Github Actions workflow

Tags: bash, github, yaml, github-actions

I want to create a variable and then pass it along in other jobs. I closely followed the answers from [another similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485275/10834788).

Right now, the variable set via `outputs` isn't coming along, just an empty value.

```
  get_main_branch_sha_short:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Get short SHA of main branch
        run: |
          git fetch --prune --unshallow
          export MAIN_BRANCH_SHA_SHORT=$(git rev-parse --short origin/main)
          echo "MAIN_BRANCH_SHA_SHORT is: $MAIN_BRANCH_SHA_SHORT"
          echo "::set-output name=main_branch_sha_short::${MAIN_BRANCH_SHA_SHORT}"

  test_get_main_branch_sha_short:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      - get_main_branch_sha_short
    steps:
      - name: test sha variable
        run: |
          echo "main_branch_sha_short is: 3.1.0-git-${{ needs.get_main_branch_sha_short.outputs.main_branch_sha_short }}"
```

The output is:

```
main_branch_sha_short is: 3.1.0-git-
```

I expect the git short version to appear here. How do I get that?

I also tried with `--trim-newlines` and it did not work.

Comment: You don't define any job outputs, your steps don't have IDs and that's no longer the syntax for an output. Read the actual docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs.  Also the post you link to has no answers.

Comment: The syntax will be deprecated but it still is in WARN mode for now. Are you saying the syntax won't work right now?

Comment: [The syntax is functional, but will only work until 31st May 2023](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/). If you still want to use it that way, you just need to definir the [job `outputs` field](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs#example-defining-outputs-for-a-job) in the first job where you set the output variables, and add an `id` to the `Get short SHA of main branch` step to refer it.

Answer (score 0):

My example:

```yml
name: Test Output
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  output-set:
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    outputs:
      test-output1: ${{ steps.output.outputs.out1 }}
      test-output2: ${{ steps.output.outputs.out2 }}
    steps:          
      - name: Set output
        id: output
        run: |
          echo "out1=Your output1" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "out2=Your output2" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          
  print:
    needs: output-set
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    steps:
      - name: Echo output
        run: |
          echo "== output =="
          echo "${{needs.output-set.outputs.test-output1}}"
          echo "${{needs.output-set.outputs.test-output2}}"
```

It's simple for you to apply to your workflow.