# NODE_ENV environment variable in Github action is not changed in separated jobs

Tags: github-actions

I've separated Github action jobs in two.

One is for setting GITHUB_ENV variables, named `set-env-variables` and another is for deployment, named `deploy`.

However every variable except "NODE_ENV" is set perfectly in `deploy` job as I intended, and "NODE_ENV" is remained to be a default value.

Here is my simplified workflow file.

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - staging

defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash

env:
  NODE_ENV: development
  DEPLOY_ENV: development

jobs:
  set-env-variables:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Check Pushed Branch'
      run: |
        BRANCH=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF##*/})

        if [ ${BRANCH} = staging ]; then
          echo "DEPLOY_ENV=staging" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "NODE_ENV=staging" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Deploy by environment'
      run: |
      echo $NODE_ENV
      echo $DEPLOY_ENV
      # do some deploying jobs...
```

when pushing to `staging` branch, `Deploy by environment` step in `deploy` job shows the result below.

```
development
staging
```

I have no idea why NODE_ENV hasn't changed, but every other variables have changed well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind the gap:

> You can make an environment variable available to any **subsequent steps in a workflow job** by defining or updating the environment variable and writing this to the `GITHUB_ENV` environment file.

*(from : [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable))*

You have a **different job**.

Use `GITHUB_OUTPUT` instead:

> Sets a step's output parameter. Note that the step will need an `id` to be defined to later retrieve the output value.

*(from: [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter))*

- [Example of setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-setting-an-output-parameter)

  ```yaml
      - name: Set color
        id: random-color-generator
        run: echo "SELECTED_COLOR=green" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
      - name: Get color

        run: echo "The selected color is ${{ steps.random-color-generator.outputs.SELECTED_COLOR }}"
  ```
- [Defining outputs for jobs - Create a map of outputs for your jobs.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs)
- [Example: Defining outputs for a job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs#example-defining-outputs-for-a-job)

  ```yaml
  jobs:
    job1:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      # Map a step output to a job output
      outputs:
        output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
        output2: ${{ steps.step2.outputs.test }}
      steps:
        - id: step1
          run: echo "test=hello" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        - id: step2
          run: echo "test=world" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    job2:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: job1
      steps:
        - env:
            OUTPUT1: ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}}
            OUTPUT2: ${{needs.job1.outputs.output2}}
          run: echo "$OUTPUT1 $OUTPUT2"
  ```
- [`needs` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#needs-context)
- [Example usage of the needs context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#needs-context)

Cf. [GitHub Action - Define Workflow Level Environment Variable Between Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63467662/367456)