# GitHub Actions to use variables set from shell

Tags: shell, environment-variables, github-actions

Goal:

In GitHub Actions, to define my commit message dynamically from shell:

```yaml
      - name: Commit changes
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7
        with:
          message: "added on $(date -I)"
```

However, it seems that I have to define a environment variable then use it. I'm following [How do I set an env var with a bash expression in GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968497/) and other help files like [this](https://dev.to/mihinduranasinghe/working-with-environment-variables-github-actions-part-2-46po), but still cannot tell how to make use of such environment variable that I've define previously. This is what I tried but failed:

```yaml
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          touch sample.js
          echo "today=$(date -I)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Commit changes
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7
        with:
          message: "added on ${today}"
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to reference an environment variable set using the `$GITHUB_ENV` environment file in the arguments to another task, you'll need to use workflow syntax to access the appropriate key of the top level `env` key, like this:

```
- name: Commit changes
  uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7
  with:
    message: "added on ${{env.today}}"
```

You can access it as a standard environment from inside of a running task, for example:

```
- name: Show an environment variable
  run: |
      echo "today is $today"
```

In that example, the expression `$today` is expanded *by the shell*,
which looks up the environment variable named `today`. You could also
write:

```
- name: Show an environment variable
  run: |
      echo "today is ${{env.today}}"
```

In this case, the expansion would be performed by github's workflow
engine *before* the `run` commands execute, so the shell would see a
literal command that looks like `echo "today is 2021-07-14"`.

---

You can accomplish something similar using [output parameters](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter), like this:

```
- name: "Set an output parameter"
  id: set_today
  run: |
    echo "::set-output name=today::$(date -I)"

- name: Commit changes
  uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7
  with:
    message: "added on ${{steps.set_today.outputs.today}}"
```

Using output parameters is a little more granular (because they are
qualified by the step id), and they won't show up in the environment
of processes started by your tasks.

Comment: Kudo! to have answered the things that I'd like to ask but don't know they exist.