# Use bash variables as parameters to a GitHub Action

Tags: linux, shell, variables, github, github-actions

I am calling a GitHub action, and I want to pass it the parameter extra_build_args with the value `--build-arg CURRENT_DD_VERSION={$VER}` (not in string) where $VER is a shell variable that I set with a specific version. When I check what was passed in I see it took the literal value {$VER} instead of resolving the variable. I set `$VER` in a different (earlier) step of the Github action. How can pass in the content of the shell variable as a parameter?

```sh
    - name: Get version
      run: |
        VER=$(cat ver.txt)
    - name: Build docker image
      uses: kciter/aws-ecr-action@v3
      with:
        //some more parameters
        extra_build_args: "--build-arg CURRENT_DD_VERSION={$VER}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Actions to use variables set from shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381640/github-actions-to-use-variables-set-from-shell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check first the syntax:

```
${VER}
# not
{$VER}
```

In your case:

```
extra_build_args: "--build-arg CURRENT_DD_VERSION=${VER}"
```

You also have the documentation "[Environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables)"

> To set custom environment variables, you need to specify the variables in the workflow file.
> You can define environment variables for a step, job, or entire workflow using the `jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env`, `jobs.<job_id>.env`, and `env` keywords.

The examples would use `$VER`
Or:

```
    extra_build_args: "--build-arg CURRENT_DD_VERSION=${{ env.VER }}"
```

Comment: Can you show an example of using environment variables in my case? I don't understand this jobs.<job_id>.steps[*] thing. What should it be in my case?

Comment: Did you test first $ENV or ${ENV}?

Comment: and using ${VER} doesn't fix it: it is still not resolved

Comment: @StackOverflow OK and `${{ env.VER }}`? (I have edited the answer)