# How to assign string from Ubuntu variable to tag_name and release_name for creating release with Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a Github Actions workflow created. At the end of the workflow, I want to create a release with a particular name and tag.

For this purpose, I am using `actions/create-release@v1` from [this repo](https://github.com/actions/create-release).

Here is my entire script:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.8.3
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.8.3"
    - name: Check python version
      run: |
        python --version
    - name: Install bdist_wheel
      run: |
        pip install wheel
    - name: Build files
      run: |
        python setup.py bdist_wheel
    - name: Check directory files
      run: | 
        ls -a
    - name: Test myExample Install
      run: |
        pip install ./dist/myExample*
    - name: Extract Version Number
      run: |
        VERSION=$(pip show myExample | grep Version | grep -E -o "([0-9]+.*)")
        echo "Extracted Version : ${VERSION}"
        VERSION_STRING="V${VERSION}"
        echo "Version String : ${VERSION_STRING}"
        RELEASE_STRING="myExample-${VERSION_STRING}"
        echo "Release String : ${RELEASE_STRING}"
    - name: Create Release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        tag_name: "${VERSION_STRING}"
        release_name: "${RELEASE_STRING}"
```

In the section `Extract Version Number`, I extract and create certain version strings that I want to use when creating a release.

I then try to apply those strings here:

```
        tag_name: "${VERSION_STRING}"
        release_name: "${RELEASE_STRING}"
```

However, it doesn't work, as the release is named as `${RELEASE_STRING}`. I tried a couple of different permutations with different brackets, quotes, etc. but nothing has worked.

How can I apply the string to here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to `Github Actions` and just realized that there are environment variables whose purpose is to pass data between runs.

My new file:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.8.3
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.8.3"
    - name: Check python version
      run: |
        python --version
    - name: Install bdist_wheel
      run: |
        pip install wheel
    - name: Build files
      run: |
        python setup.py bdist_wheel
    - name: Check directory files
      run: | 
        ls -a
    - name: Test myExample Install
      run: |
        pip install ./dist/myExample*
    - name: Extract Version Number
      run: |
        VERSION=$(pip show myExample | grep Version | grep -E -o "([0-9]+.*)")
        echo "Extracted Version : ${VERSION}"
        VERSION_STRING="V${VERSION}"
        echo "Version String : ${VERSION_STRING}"
        RELEASE_STRING="myExample-${VERSION_STRING}"
        echo "Release String : ${RELEASE_STRING}"
        echo "VERSION=$VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "VERSION_STRING=$VERSION_STRING" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "RELEASE_STRING=$RELEASE_STRING" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: Create Release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        tag_name: ${{env.VERSION}}
        release_name: ${{env.RELEASE_STRING}}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968497/how-do-i-set-an-env-var-with-a-bash-expression-in-github-actions) is what I used and made me realize what I was doing wrong.