# Terraform Cloud not recognizing TF_VAR environment variable in Github Actions

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-cloud

In my Github actions pipeline I use the Terraform Cloud workflows like this:

```
terraform:
    name: "Terraform Plan"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: write
    env:
      TF_CLOUD_ORGANIZATION: "xxx"
      TF_API_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}"
      TF_WORKSPACE: "xxx"
      CONFIG_DIRECTORY: "./infrastructure"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set variables
        run: echo "TF_VAR_image_tag=$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | cut -c 1-6)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Upload Configuration
        uses: hashicorp/tfc-workflows-github/actions/upload-configuration@v1.0.4
        id: plan-upload
        with:
          directory: ./
          workspace: ${{ env.TF_WORKSPACE }}
          speculative: true

      - name: Create Plan Run
        uses: hashicorp/tfc-workflows-github/actions/create-run@v1.0.4
        id: plan-run
        with:
          workspace: ${{ env.TF_WORKSPACE }}
          configuration_version: ${{ steps.plan-upload.outputs.configuration_version_id }}
          plan_only: true
```

In which I try to set `image_tag` Terraform variable by setting the `TF_VAR_image_tag` environment variable. However, I keep getting `The root module input variable \"image_tag\" is not set, and has no default value`. Which implies that Terraform did not receive a value for that variable. I defined the `image_tag` like so:

```
variable "image_tag" {
  type = string
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [the "create-run" GitHub Action](https://github.com/hashicorp/tfc-workflows-github/blob/main/actions/create-run/action.yml) which internally runs the "tfci" tool, and is specifically running the `tfci run create` command.

[`tfci`](https://github.com/hashicorp/tfc-workflows-tooling) is an alternative to Terraform CLI which more directly follows the shape of the Terraform Cloud API, whereas Terraform CLI's cloud integration is designed to adapt the normal Terraform CLI workflow to work with Terraform Cloud.

That tool implements a similar `TF_VAR_` convention as Terraform CLI does, but it has a significant difference: it doesn't have access to the configuration and so it cannot detect automatically what types each of your input variables has. Terraform CLI uses the type of the variable to make it more convenient to pass the value for a string variable without having to write it in full Terraform expression syntax (with quotes), but `tfci` requires all input variables to be written in the full Terraform expression syntax.

In your case, that means that your `TF_VAR_image_tag` environment variable value must contain a valid HCL string literal, including the quotes, like `"abc123"`, instead of just a naked token like `abc123`.

Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation on exactly what format is expected for the file that `GITHUB_ENV` refers to -- the documentation only describes how to append to it with some trivial examples, and doesn't document exactly what syntax GitHub is expecting -- but assuming that GitHub parses this format in a way that treats quotes literally then the following might work:

```
echo "TF_VAR_image_tag=\"$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | cut -c 1-6)\"" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

After being interpreted by the shell, the `GITHUB_ENV` file would contain something like the following:

```
TF_VAR_image_tag="abc123"
```

...whereas your current code would generate this:

```
TF_VAR_image_tag=abc123
```

Internally within Terraform Cloud, the execution environment will generate a `terraform.tfvars` file that includes `image_tag =`  followed by literally whatever you put in that environment variable. So without the quotes, the syntax of that file would be invalid:

```
image_tag = abc123
```

That's invalid because `abc123` is the syntax for a reference to a symbol/variable, and those are not allowed in `.tfvars` files. Terraform will report "variables are not allowed here".

Instead, the generated file must contain this, with the quotes around the string:

```
image_tag = "abc123"
```

...and so the environment variable value MUST also include those quotes, so that the generated `terraform.tfvars` file will be valid.

Comment: Escaping the extra quotes did the trick. Thanks for the elaboration. It improved my understanding of Terraform Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57969570/1198321) for how to set environment variables in GitHub Actions. Just doing an `export xxx=yyy` doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the code in my question according to that answer but I still receive the same error.

Comment: I seems that the variable has been passed but is not allowed for some reason...

{"severity":"error","summary":"Variables not allowed","detail":"Variables may not be used here.","range":{"filename":"/home/tfc-agent/.tfc-agent/component/terraform/runs/run-oMCvgMbE1QJJhuDW/terraform.tfvars","start":{"line":2,"column":13,"byte":2450},"end":{"line":2,"column":19,"byte":2456}},"snippet":{"context":null,"code":"image_tag = ee18a8"

Comment: It seems that setting the value `54f2c07516febca14eaf247099693360a81290c1` to tf variable `image_tag` is not allowed. I don't understand why.

Comment: With a quick google for that error message I found [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24391), which suggests that you are not quoting the value. Since it's coming in through an env var, that doesn't seem right. Also, the context of that error message suggests you are actually setting `image_tag = ee18a8` somewhere in your code rather than relying on the env var, so I would check for that

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is going on here but some information that might be helpful: Terraform Cloud automatically generates `terraform.tfvars` before running Terraform, and includes in there any input variables that are coming from locations other than the source code itself. I expect that must include those set by environment variables because Terraform Cloud's remote execution environment cannot automatically "see" the environment variables in your client, so it must be sending those via the API and writing them into that file so that the remote Terraform CLI can find them.